# Compiling class in Memory and storing them in Database in Java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, db2, blob, in-memory

I want to compile a class (for example Test1) in memory and directly store the byte code  in a database as a BLOB.

Additionally I also want to compile a new class (Test2) which calls Test1 which is stored in the database. So I need to load this class from the database to compile Test2. Is that even possible, and if yes how could I do that?

I have read about the InMemoryCompiler and the DatabaseClassLoader, but I'm not sure if thats the right thing to work with.

https://github.com/trung/InMemoryJavaCompiler

[How can I load java class from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329685/how-can-i-load-java-class-from-database)

If someone just know how to solve the first problem, that would also be great.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Why? This is a very fragile thing to do.

Comment: And you'd almost certainly use up more memory with this scheme, too.  That linked answer pretty much _is_ what you'd have to do, ignoring some minor details.  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve, that you see this as the solution?

Comment: I need to compile a new class, which has reference to other classes which are already stored as.class in a database or the Filesystem. But in the database/filesystem are stored 1000 of classes, so I dont want to load the whole package, I only want to load the .class files I really need. So how can I compile the new Class during runtime, that it knows the external references?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` and related classes.

It's a bit tricky though, since `javax.tools` is not well documented. By trial and error, I found out that we need a special `javax.tools.JavaFileManager` that overrides both `list()` and `inferBinaryName()`.

I simply stored the byte code for the compiled classes in a hash map, but changing that part to a database shouldn't be too difficult.

```
package simple.tools;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject.Kind;
import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import javax.tools.FileObject;
import javax.tools.ForwardingJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.JavaFileManager;

class NamedJavaFileObject extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
    final String name;
    protected NamedJavaFileObject(String name, Kind kind) {
        super(URI.create(name.replace('.', '/') + kind.extension), kind);
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class SimpleCompiler {

    public static JavaFileObject sourceFile(String name, String source) {
        return inputFile(name, Kind.SOURCE, source);
    }

    private static JavaFileObject inputFile(String name, Kind kind, String content) {
        return new NamedJavaFileObject(name, kind) {
            @Override
            public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean b) {
                return content;
            }
        };
    }

    private static JavaFileObject inputFile(String name, Kind kind, byte[] content) {
        return new NamedJavaFileObject(name, kind) {
            @Override
            public InputStream openInputStream() {
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
            }
        };
    }

    private JavaFileObject outputFile(String name, Kind kind) {
        return new NamedJavaFileObject(name, kind) {
            @Override
            public OutputStream openOutputStream() {
                return outputStream(name);
            }
        };
    }

    private OutputStream outputStream(String name) {
        return new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void close() {
                storeClass(name, toByteArray());
            }
        };
    }

    private void storeClass(String name, byte[] bytes) {
        classes.put(name, bytes);
        JavaFileObject file = inputFile(name, Kind.CLASS, bytes);
        int dot = name.lastIndexOf('.');
        String pkg = dot == -1 ? "" : name.substring(0, dot);
        packages.computeIfAbsent(pkg, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(file);
    }

    private final Map<String, byte[]> classes = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, List<JavaFileObject>> packages = new HashMap<>();

    private final ClassLoader loader = new ClassLoader() {
        @Override
        protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            byte[] bytes = classes.get(name);
            if (bytes == null) throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
            return super.defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        }
    };

    private final JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

    private final JavaFileManager manager =
    new ForwardingJavaFileManager<JavaFileManager>(compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null)) {
        @Override
        public JavaFileObject getJavaFileForOutput(Location loc, String name, Kind kind, FileObject obj) {
            return outputFile(name, kind);
        }

        @Override
        public Iterable<JavaFileObject> list(Location loc, String pkg, Set<Kind> kinds, boolean rec) throws IOException {
            List<JavaFileObject> files = packages.get(pkg);
            if (files != null) return files;
            else return super.list(loc, pkg, kinds, rec);
        }

        @Override
        public String inferBinaryName(Location loc, JavaFileObject file) {
            if (file instanceof NamedJavaFileObject) return ((NamedJavaFileObject)file).name;
            else return super.inferBinaryName(loc, file);
        }
    };

    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return loader.loadClass(name);
    }

    public Class<?> compile(String name, String source) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        compile(sourceFile(name, source));
        return loadClass(name);
    }

    public void compile(JavaFileObject... files) {
        compile(Arrays.asList(files));
    }

    public void compile(List<JavaFileObject> files) {
        if (files.isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("No input files");
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> collector = new DiagnosticCollector<>();
        CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, manager, collector, null, null, files);
        boolean success = task.call();
        check(success, collector);
    }

    private void check(boolean success, DiagnosticCollector<?> collector) {
        for (Diagnostic<?> diagnostic : collector.getDiagnostics()) {
            if (diagnostic.getKind() == Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR) {
                throw new RuntimeException(diagnostic.getMessage(Locale.US));
            }
        }
        if (! success) throw new RuntimeException("Unknown error");
    }
}
```

Example:

```
SimpleCompiler compiler = new SimpleCompiler();
Class<?> fooCls = compiler.compile("Foo", "class Foo {}");
// later...
Class<?> barCls = compiler.compile("Bar", "class Bar { /* use Foo...*/ }");
```

See https://gitlab.com/jcsahnwaldt/simple-java-tools.